# LINQ to SQL MAX in WHERE clause

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I am new to Linq so as expected I have encountered difficulties.
What I am trying to achieve is this:

```
SELECT id, name, password
FROM users u
WHERE u.id = (SELECT MAX(u1.id) FROM users u1);
```

My Linq is:

```
var dbUsers = from u in context.Users
              where u.Id == (context.Users.Max(u1 => u1.Id))
              select u;
```

But I always end with the following exception:

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'Bla.Users'. Only primitive
>   types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this
>   context.

Here is the users class:

```
public class Users
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is my context class:

```
 public class EFDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users{ get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to select the `ID` property

```
var dbUsers = from u in context.Users
              where u.Id == (context.Users.Select(u1 => u1.Id).Max())
              select u;
```

Comment: Same issue. I forgot to mention that I am using MySQL as data source.

Comment: If I move the Max aggregate outside the query, things do work: int id = context.Users.Max(u1 => u1.Id) and then var dbUsers = from u in context.Users
              where u.Id == id
              select u;

Answer (score 1):

I usually do my LINQing in lambda format...

```
var dbUsers = DataContext.Users
    .Where(u => u.Id == (DataContext.Users.Max(u1 => u1.Id)))
    .Select(u => new
    {
       Id = u.Id,
       Name = u.Name,
       Password = u.Password
    });
```

If you want the comprehension format...

```
var dbUsers = from u in DataContext.Users
    where u.Id == (DataContext.Users.Max(u1 => u1.Id))
    select new 
    {
       Id = u.Id,
       Name = u.Name,
       Password = u.Password
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I am getting same exception.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a `let` statement:

```
var dbUsers = from u in context.Users
              let int maxId = context.Users.Max(u1 => u1.Id)
              where u.Id == maxId
              select u;
```

Comment: Same error unfortunately. The issue resides in this subquery context.Users.Max(u1 => u1.Id) but I can't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

Please let me know if this one solves your problem:

```
var dbUser = (from u in context.Users
              orderby u.Id descending).FirstOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use lambda expressions:

```
var dbUser = context.Users.First(u => u.Id== (context.Users.Select(u2
=> u2.Id).Max()));
```

or:

```
var dbUser = context.Users.OrderByDescending(u => u.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```